# Complicated joining on multiple id's

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
id | user_id | code  | type | time
-----------------------------------
2    2         fdsa    r      1358300000
3    2         barf    r      1358311000
4    2         yack    r      1358311220
5    3         surf    r      1358311000
6    3         yooo    r      1358300000
7    4         poot    r      1358311220
```

I want to get the concatenated 'code' column for user 2 and user 3 for each matching time.

I want to receive a result set like this:

```
code     | time
-------------------------------
fdsayooo   1358300000
barfsurf   1358311000
```

Please note that there is no yackpoot code because the query was not looking for user 4.

Comment: Why only users 2 and 3?  What order should the code be in?  Is there some sort of 'resolution' for timestamps, or do you want **exact** matches for time?  And... _WHY_ are you doing this?

Comment: +1 @Clockwork-Muse The Why eludes me completely as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` function. Try this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(code SEPARATOR '') code, time 
FROM tbl 
WHERE user_id in (2, 3)
GROUP BY time
HAVING COUNT(time) = 2;
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c1bb/5/0)**

Comment: +1, but adding `ORDER BY id` to the GROUP_CONCAT would likely make the results more predictable.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `GROUP_CONCAT`, but you are missing a lot of details in your question to provide a good example. This should get you started:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(code), time 
FROM myTable 
WHERE user_id in (2, 3)
GROUP BY time;
```

Missing details are:

1. Is there an order required? Not sure how ordering would be done useing grouping, would need to test if critical
2. Need other fields? If so you will likely end up needing to do a sub-select or secondary query.
3. Do you only want results with multiple times?
4. Do you really want no separator between values in the results column (specify the delimiter with `SEPARATOR ''` in the `GROUP_CONCAT`

Notes:

1. You can add more fields to the GROUP BY if you want to do it by something else (like `user_id` and `time`).